# GeoTIFF changes location relative to vector layer when panning map screen

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, pan

The problem that I have is two layers are not positioning themselves correctly on the map screen, and shift position further when I pan the screen (they move closer or further away from each other, depending on the pan direction).  One layer is a GeoTIFF that is correctly registered and uses CRS EPSG:32625, the other layer is a vector (country outline) that is also correctly registered with CRS EPSG:32625. The map canvas is also using the same projection.

Is there a setting somewhere that I have activated by accident?

UPDATE: it appears that that it is only the GeoTIFF that is problematic, I uploaded it to georeferencer.com and it located perfectly, while in QGIS it is constantly offset/jumps around when panning.

The data for the file reads:

Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: /Users/file.tif
Size is 2047, 2079
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 25N",
BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
ID["EPSG",4326]],
CONVERSION["UTM zone 25N",
METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
ID["EPSG",9807]],
PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
ID["EPSG",8801]],
PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-33,
ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
ID["EPSG",8802]],
PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
ID["EPSG",8805]],
PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
ID["EPSG",8806]],
PARAMETER["False northing",0,
LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
ID["EPSG",8807]]],
CS[Cartesian,2],
AXIS["(E)",east,
ORDER[1],
LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
AXIS["(N)",north,
ORDER[2],
LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
USAGE[
SCOPE["topographic mapping."],
AREA["Between 36°W and 30°W, northern hemisphere between equator and 84°N, onshore and offshore. Greenland."],
BBOX[0,-36,84,-30]],
ID["EPSG",32625]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (554638.780000000027940,7637602.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (40.000000000000000,-40.000000000000000)
Metadata:
AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  554638.780, 7637602.000) ( 31d38'35.99"W, 68d50'39.40"N)
Lower Left  (  554638.780, 7554442.000) ( 31d41'14.39"W, 68d 5'55.08"N)
Upper Right (  636518.780, 7637602.000) ( 29d36'48.13"W, 68d48'57.38"N)
Lower Right (  636518.780, 7554442.000) ( 29d43'22.79"W, 68d 4'16.86"N)
Center      (  595578.780, 7596022.000) ( 30d40' 0.40"W, 68d27'37.93"N)
Band 1 Block=2047x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=2047x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=2047x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue

I am using QGIS version 3.22.3 on a Mac.

Comment: Please post a link(WeTransfer, DropBox, etc) to your data.

Comment: Is your map canvas also using the same projection? It can be changed with a button in the bottom right of the screen. And how far are you panning?

Comment: The raster image may have overview layers (resampled versions with bigger pixel size). Perhaps there has happened some shift in the processing.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: I´ve just updated the post to provide more information, I hope this helps to clarify the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be related to this: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/46917. I've noticed the same behavior using XYZ tile layers.

Comment: Yes! This appears to be very similar, I do not recall having this issue with previous versions of QGIS. I will try going back to QGIS Odense and see if that works. Thank you.

Comment: Same here using a project that was fine prior to 3.22 upgrade. Bizarrely, the same project works fine on my M1 Mac mini, but displays this problem on my Intel Mac Air. Also appears to mistakenly associate CRSs - a blank project claimed OSGB Open Zoomstack was WGS84 Pseudo Mercator when imported...